# Write a simple Function that works like "std::cout" but adds a Line Break at the End

Tags: c++, function, stl, stream, cout

In C++ there is a standard library function called `cout`, which lets me send text to the console. I am sure you know that.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
cout << "Some Text " << 15 << " Other Text";
```

To do a linebreak at the end, I need to use `endl`.

```
cout << "Some Text " << 15 << " Other Text" << endl;
```

How can I write a function named `coutl` which behaves like `cout` but also adds a likebreak? I want to use the same syntax that `cout` uses, especially the `<<` operator.

```
coutl << "Some Text " << 15 << " Other Text"; // coutl should add a linebreak
```

Comment: `cout` isn't a function, it is an object.

Comment: you can either use endl (which you do not want to) or "\n" at the end.

Comment: I'm pretty sure such isn't possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By creating a little proxy object which adds `<< endl` in its destructor:

```
class AddEndl
{
public:
  AddEndl(std::ostream& os) : _holder(new Holder(os)) {}

  template <class T>
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (const AddEndl& l, const T& t)
  {
    return (l._holder->_os) << t;
  }

private:
  struct Holder {
    Holder (std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}
    ~Holder () { _os << std::endl; }

    std::ostream& _os;
  };

  mutable std::shared_ptr<Holder> _holder;
}
```

Then you need a function so that you will get a temporary:

```
AddEndl wrap(std::ostream& os)
{
  return AddEndl(os);
}
```

This should then work:

```
wrap(std::cout) << "Hello";
```

**UPDATE:**

I move the destructor which adds a `std::endl` to an inner object owned by a `std::shared_ptr<>` so that the example doesn't depend on Copy Elision anymore.

Comment: Nice. Much better than mine. Will work for any iostream object.

Comment: The idea is solid but its execution relies on copy elision though.

Comment: Actually, I just tried out - the code doesn't work for me. I added a templated << operator in the AddEndl class, obviously. But I got multiple endls - not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with just a non-temp object created on the stack & which has full function scope. How will the object ever know what this is the last of the chained calls to the `<< operator`?

You can try hacks like these

```
class coutl
{
    public:
    ~coutl()
    {
        cout<<endl;
    }

    template<class T>
    coutl &operator<<(const T &x)
    {
        cout<<x;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    coutl()<<"Hello"<<10<<"World";
    coutl()<<"Hello"<<20<<"World";
}
```

Another similar hack using the destructor

```
class myostream
{
    public:
    ~myostream()
    {
        cout<<endl;
    }

    template<class T>
    myostream &operator<<(const T &x)
    {
        cout<<x;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    {
        myostream coutl;
        coutl<<"Hello"<<10<<"World";
    }

    {
        myostream coutl;
        coutl<<"Hello"<<10<<"World";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the code

```
cout << "Some Text " << 15 << " Other Text" << endl;
```

calls the operator function(s)

```
// (pseudo code)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, [type] obj);
```

several times for each use of the `<<` operators.
To achieve what you want you would need to create a class that behaves like `std::ostream`, but 'magically' knows when the 'last' call to `operator<<` is issued and appends a linebreak. That's not possible IMHO without another object that keeps track of the statements scope.

Answer (score 0):

`coutl << "Some Text " << 15 << " Other Text"; // coutl should add a linebreak`

Your idea can't be realize. In fact, `cout << str1;` is equivalent to `cout.operator<<(str1)` which returns a reference of cout itself. So `cout << a << b << c;` can be resolvd to  `((cout << a) << b) << c;` It doesn't know when is the last call to insert an linebreak.