# Operator << in a user defined method

Tags: c++, operators

I was trying to write a method that would take parameters using the `>>` operator as parameters similar to `std::cin` but I don't know how. Is it possible to create this kind of method that would take this stream like parameter, convert it properly (for example convert all ints to strings etc) and then save to an std::string variable?

Here is an example of how I would like to run the function:

```
int i = 0;
myMethod << "some text" << i << "moar text";
```

Inside that method I would like to take those parameters and store in a string.

### Edit

I will try to explain exactly what this application is about: I Am trying to make a Clogger singleton class which will be used to save logs to a file. With this construction, I can call `*CLogger::instance() << "log stuff";` from anywhere in the code and that's OK. Thanks to answers from this topic I have come to this. The problem is that each `operator<<` I use, then the object is going to be called. So if I do *CLogger::instance() << "log stuff " << " more stuff " << " even more";` this method(?) is going to be called 3 times:

```
template<typename T>
    CLogger& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        ...

        return *this;
    }
```

That's not good for me as I intend to add some text before and after each log line. For example I would always like to add time before and `std::endl` after. Following the example I gave instead of getting:

```
[00:00] log stuff more stuff even more
```

I would get:

```
[00:00] log stuff 
[00:00]  more stuff 
[00:00]  even more
```

So I made an attempt to remove this behaviour by changing the method like this:

```
template<typename T>
    CLogger& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        ostringstream stream;
        stream << t;
        m_catString += stream.str();

        if (stream.str() == "\n")
        {
            push_back(m_catString);
            m_catString.clear();
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

This way the program knows when to push new log line if I add `"\n"` at the end. Its nearly ok, as I bet I will forget to add this. Is there any more clever way?

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials and questions on this, every single introductory c++ book covers it. Try reading one and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Also fix your title. You have the wrong operator there.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you for the hint i have fixed it. The problem is that this topic is not so basic, I find it hard to find any straightforward info about it. Also the C++ books dont really say anything excessive about it.

Comment: You probably should use the power of search engines before asking.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to a method using `<<`, you need an object.

Something like this:

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    A& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << t;
        data += stream.str();
        return *this;
    }
    std::string data;
};

// ...

A a;
a << "Hello " << 34 << " World";
std::cout << a.data;
```

---

Regarding your update:

The most obvious thing is to implement the operator in `CLogger` instead and get rid of the `Pusher` class; that would let you write `*CLogger::instance() << "sample text" << 10;`

If you can't do that for some reason (you're giving out information piecemeal, so it's hard to tell), you can declare `Pusher` a friend and use the same method as everywhere else:

```
struct Pusher
{
    template<typename T>
    Pusher& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << t;
        CLogger::instance()->push_back(stream.str());
        return *this;
    }

};
```

Comment: I am very close now, I have updated my code with regard to your answer but I would aprieciate a followup answer.

Comment: Please tell me what more information you need and I will provide it. I would really like to call the operator like you specified. Thats exacly what I need but like you said I cannot run it like that: `error: invalid operands of types ‘CLogger*’ and ‘const char [12]’ to binary ‘operator<<’`

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You forgot a `*`.

Comment: You are right, was just about to write that. Thank you. Also I had to remove refference from the `push_back` parameter.

Comment: However, I have just noticed a problem. I can call `*CLogger::instance() << 10;` but I cannot call `*CLogger::instance() << 10 << "test"` as i get an error `error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(const char [5])’ is ambiguous`... Any idea? So now I cant use strings with to_string and cant use integers without it.

Comment: I have just realised that each time I add another `operator<<`, ie when I do `*CLogger::instance() << 1 << 2 << 3;` the method `push_back` is run 3 times... This is problematic for me because in this case I cannot add something to the obtained string at the front and at the end, as they would be added 3 times. Although I doubt it, but is there any fast solution / workaround for this?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You need to explain what you actually want to do, including all the details. There is no point in trying to answer a question that keeps changing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81518/discussion-between-lukasz-przenioslo-and-molbdnilo).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is creating a class `class Method` and then overload the `operator<<`,  [operators overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

```
template<class T>
Method &operator<<(const T &x)
{
    // Do whatever you like
    return *this;
}
```

Then you can use it like :

```
Method myMethod;
myMethod << ... ;
```

you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987860/write-a-simple-function-that-works-like-stdcout-but-adds-a-line-break-at-the) about creating a `cout`-like class 
std::cin and std::cout are not functions by the way

**EDIT**

```
class CLogger
{
  ...

  template<typename T>
  CLogger& operator<<(const T& t)
  {
     push_back(std::to_string(t));
     return *this;
  }


};
```

You don't have to create a class Pusher, just overload the operator in your first class, now you can use it with your object :

`myCLogger << t; // this would call the function push back`

Comment: Thank you for editing. My CLogger class is a singleton class that I have created using this tutorial: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html In this case I am reffering to all methods and members using `CLogger::instance()->myMethodOrMember`. I cant figure out how to call the newly created object then. I thought maybe `CLogger::instance << "test"` but nope...